The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed". for one route only
This route in web.php for main page
 Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@index');

if i run php artisan optimize, or artisan route:cache, the page become error 405
Oops! An Error Occurred. The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".

if i run php artisan route:clear, it will normal again, then if run optimize, it will show error 405 again. and its only happened for that page only. other page, can open smoothly.
Route::get('/new_link', 'App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@index');
if the route i add for example /new_link, it can open if did optimize/route cache, the problem if i only use '/'
is there any config i missed? i just upgrade from laravel 7 to laravel 10.
thank you

Does your Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\IndexController@index'); belong to a group/prefix? (ex: localhost/some/where/) where the last "/" is the IndexController@index. Or is it on the top route localhost/. Like what the downvoted answer below, check your route list and see if there is a duplicate route already declared. (duplicate endpoint "/" but with POST/PUT/DEL or something)

Checking only the provided routes there is not problem. This will depend on how you structure your routes
